# Eclipse deployment code isn't taking into consideration any changes

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, deployment, save

From one day to the next my eclipse act weird.
When I do any changes and then save them, Eclipse doesn't take them in consideration until I do a "clean project".
Before it's wasn't the case and I could even make changes while debugging.

Do you have any lead on why it does that?

Comment: Do you have "Project -> Build Automatically" checked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it's a metadata problem.

Just close Eclipse and navigate to your workspace folder. Delete the .metadata folder and restart Eclipse. The project should build as it should be :)

When you delete the .metadata folder, things like the Class Path are being validated again.

Beware:
Your Eclipse settings are gone after you delete the .metadata folder. So you have to import you project again, your theme is gone. Everything must be set again.

Comment: You are talking about the ``.settings`` folder, right? ``.metadata`` exists in the workspace, not in each project.

Comment: Fixed it. My mistake :)